# Spark 2.3.1 structured streaming kafka ClassNotFound

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to use Spark 2.3.1 structured streaming with Kafka. Getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:190)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
  at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
  at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
  ... 51 more
```

Request advise.

**Scala code (using IntelliJ 2018.1):**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("test3")
    import org.apache.log4j._
    getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession.
      builder.
      master("local").
      appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount").
      getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val lines = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "t_tweets")
      .load()

    lines.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[(String)]

    // Split the lines into words
    val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))

    // Generate running word count
    val wordCounts = words.groupBy("value").count()

    val query = wordCounts.writeStream
      .outputMode("complete")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

**Build.sbt :**

```
name := "scalaSpark3"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1" % "provided"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "1.1.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.3.1" % "provided"
```

**Full error log:**

```
objc[7301]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10c6334c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10c6bf4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
test3

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
    at test$.main(test.scala:33)
    at test.main(test.scala)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
    ... 3 more
```

My code is based the sample code here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Answer (score 1):

Kafka integration is not included on your Spark classpath

Therefore, remove `provided`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.1" % "provided"
```

And make sure you create an uber jar before you run Spark Submit